# Не корректно сравниваются данные

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2

Я сделал программу для проверки правильности логина и пароля, все логины и пароля записаны в два файла: `password`, `login`, после чего данные сравниваются, если такого пароля или логина нет, то выдается ошибка, но почему то при введение корректного пароля все ровно получаю ошибку.

Как это исправить?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def App_Date(self):
        with open('password.txt') as f:
            myListPassword = [line.split() for line in f]

        user_password = self.lineEdit_2.text()

        print(myListPassword)

        with open('login.txt') as f:
            myListLogin = [line.split() for line in f]

        user_login = self.lineEdit.text()

        print(myListLogin)
        print(len(myListPassword))

        number_password = 0

        for i in range(len(myListPassword)):
           if user_password == myListPassword[number_password]:
               print("Пароль совпал")
           else:
               print("Пароль не совпал!")
           print(user_password)
           print(myListPassword[number_password])
           number_password += 1

    def User_Admin(self):
        pass

    def Register(self):
        pass

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(307, 136)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 307, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.App_Date)
        #   self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "E-mail address:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Password:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Войти"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Зарегестрироваться"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Покажите, что у вас `print`-ы печатают, может понятнее станет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я плохо понимаю вашу логику проверки логина и пароля. 
Ваша идея с двумя файлами текстового формата - плохая.
Вам надо посмотреть в сторону БД.

Добавьте `[0]` в две строки.

```
...
    for i in range(len(myListPassword)):
    # --------------------------------------------------->vvv
       if user_password == myListPassword[number_password][0]:     # + [0]
           print("Пароль совпал")
       else:
           print("Пароль не совпал!")
       print(user_password)
    # ------------------------------------->vvv   
       print(myListPassword[number_password][0])                   # + [0]
       number_password += 1

...
```

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ** код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, **НИКОГДА**. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Comment: в одном файле хранятся данные обычных пользователей, а в другом администратора.

Comment: @Settings да, еще, вы должны показывать тестовые примеры того что у вас находится в этих файлах.

Comment: то конкурсная работа, по этому времени для БД у меня нету(

Comment: @Settings, sorry, это не очень хороший вариант для конкурсной работы. На данном ресурсе вы можете найти все, в том числе и примеры по работе с БД.

Comment: примеры то есть, но я не понимаю принципа работы, если вы можете, то объясните работу БД на вот этом примере.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался в проблеме, полученные данные таким путем нельзя корректно сравнивать, их нужно записать в таком виде: ["admin@gmail.com", "none@gmail.com".

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def settings(self):
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText('Пожалуйста введите e-mail')
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText('Пожалуйста введите пароль')

    def App_Date(self):

        password_check = False
        login_check = False

        login_check_admin = False
        password_check_admin = False

        user_password = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        user_login = self.lineEdit.text()
        if len(user_password) != 0 and len(user_login) != 0:
            with open('password.txt') as f:
                myListPassword = [line.split() for line in f]

            myListPassword_2 = [item for sublist in myListPassword for item in sublist]
            number_password = 0

            for i in range(len(myListPassword_2)):
                if str(user_password) == str(myListPassword_2[number_password]):
                    password_check = True
                else:
                    pass
                number_password += 1


            with open('login.txt') as f:
                myListLogin = [line.split() for line in f]

            myListLogin_2 = [item for sublist in myListLogin for item in sublist]
            number_login = 0

            for i in range(len(myListLogin_2)):
                if str(user_login) == str(myListLogin_2[number_login]):
                    login_check = True
                else:
                    pass
                number_login += 1

            if password_check == True and login_check == True:
                if number_password == number_login:
                    msg = QMessageBox()
                    msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
                    msg.setText("ИНФОРМАЦИЯ")
                    msg.setInformativeText('Вход в профиль пользователя выполнен')
                    msg.setWindowTitle("ИНФОРМАЦИЯ")
                    msg.exec_()
                else:
                    msg = QMessageBox()
                    msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
                    msg.setText("ОШИБКА")
                    msg.setInformativeText('Не верный логин или пароль')
                    msg.setWindowTitle("ОШИБКА")
                    msg.exec_()

            else:
                with open('password_admin.txt') as f:
                    myListPassword_admin = [line.split() for line in f]

                myListPassword_admin = [item for sublist in myListPassword_admin for item in sublist]
                number_password_admin = 0

                for i in range(len(myListPassword_admin)):
                    if str(user_password) == str(myListPassword_admin[number_password_admin]):
                        print(myListPassword_admin[number_password_admin])
                        password_check_admin = True
                    else:
                        pass
                    number_password_admin += 1


                with open('login_admin.txt') as f:
                    myListLogin_admin = [line.split() for line in f]

                myListLogin_admin = [item for sublist in myListLogin_admin for item in sublist]
                number_login_admin = 0
                print(myListLogin_admin)

                for i in range(len(myListLogin_admin)):
                    if str(user_login) == str(myListLogin_admin[number_login_admin]):
                        print(myListLogin_admin[number_login_admin])
                        login_check_admin = True
                    else:
                        pass
                    number_login_admin += 1

                if password_check_admin == True and login_check_admin == True:
                    if number_password_admin == number_login_admin:
                        msg = QMessageBox()
                        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
                        msg.setText("ИНФОРМАЦИЯ")
                        msg.setInformativeText('Вход в профиль администратора выполнен')
                        msg.setWindowTitle("ИНФОРМАЦИЯ")
                        msg.exec_()
                    else:
                        msg = QMessageBox()
                        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
                        msg.setText("ОШИБКА")
                        msg.setInformativeText('Не верный логин или пароль')
                        msg.setWindowTitle("ОШИБКА")
                        msg.exec_()
                else:
                    msg = QMessageBox()
                    msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
                    msg.setText("ОШИБКА")
                    msg.setInformativeText('Логин или пароль не соответсвуют')
                    msg.setWindowTitle("ОШИБКА")
                    msg.exec_()

        else:
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            msg.setText("ОШИБКА")
            msg.setInformativeText('Обязательные поля не заполнены.')
            msg.setWindowTitle("ОШИБКА")
            msg.exec_()

    def User(self):
        pass

    def Admin(self):
        pass

    def Register(self):
        pass

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(307, 136)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 307, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.App_Date)
        #   self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.)

        self.settings()

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "E-mail адрес:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пароль:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Войти"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Зарегестрироваться"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```